# HarmonicNumber Sum

Tags: calculus

Could you find where it come from
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k H_k}{k+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{1}{2} \left(-2^{2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \, _3F_2\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}};1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}};\frac{1}{2}\right)+4+\sqrt{2} \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)-\sqrt{2} \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)+\log (2) \left(\pi  \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)\right)\right)+\pi  \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right) \left(\log (2)+2 \left(\sqrt{2}+\gamma +\pi  \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: The polygamma and hypergeometric functions on the right have well-known series expansions. Have you tried using them to see where they might lead ?

Comment: I do not how to manage the  hypergeometric functions